# Проблемы с записью файла при передаче

Tags: c++, кодировка, visual-c++

Здравствуйте! Передача файла не работает как выяснилось для расширений .pdf и .doc.

- .pdf записывает все, только при открытии говорит, что файл поврежден и не может быть открыт. А так по размеру судя - исходный файл 210 КБ (215 118 байт), а записывается в новый файл - на флешку пишу - 210 КБ (216 058 байт)
- .doc при делении на блоки считывает в буфер "кракозябры" и отказывается записывать сразу же начиная с первого блока, вылетая с необработанным исключением.

Файлы открываю "C:\1.pdf", "D:\7.doc" `"C:\\1.pdf"`, `"D:\\7.doc"` ,режим -'rb' (2 cлэша в имени - здесь они не отображаются почему-то)

```
// Клиент  
//Прием файла f:
int nbytes = recv( my_socket, &buff[0], sizeof(buff), 0 ); 
if ( nbytes == 0) { 
    printf("\nПередача файла завершена\n"); 
    yes = false; 
    continue; 
} 
if (nbytes < 0) { 
    printf("Ошибка в передаче файла \n"); 
    return -1; 
} 
fwrite(buff, 1, nbytes, RecFile); 
strcpy(&buff1[0], "Принимаю поблочно файл!"); 
int n1 = strlen(buff1); 
send(my_socket, buff1, (n1-1), 0); goto f; }
```

На метки и отправка серверу "Принимаю файл" не обращайте внимания, это пока черновое все, все равно потом все в графический режим переносить.

Все, все проблемы решены, файлы отлично передаются и записываются правильно!) Проверила уже для многих расширений, все работает)Огромное спасибо всем за помощь!)

Comment: @АннаХатико, файл RecFile открыт с "wb" ? или тоже с rb?

Заодно распечатайте nbytes у клиента и сервера (в send()). Посмотрите, совпадают или нет?

Comment: @avp подозрительная разница по длине? Как раз на расширение переводов строки?

А шутка насчёт "rb" -- хм... Видимо вопрос был -- "wb" или "w"?

Comment: Я надеюсь, что @АннаХатико открывает файлы с 'b'. И на чтение и на запись. Об этом много раз говорили. Без 'b' работать с бинарными файлами нельзя, они будут считываться неверно. На мой взгляд текстовый режим - пережиток прошлого и его стоило бы вообще убрать.

Comment: @mikelsv На святое покусились? Великий У. Гейтс накажет! Сначала текстовый режим убери, а потом и обратные слеши... А дальше что? Обучение программированию под ms dos на ассемблере и турбопаскале?

Comment: @АннаХатико, в вопросе добавил обратные апострофы вокруг строк с двойными обратными слешами.

Comment: @АннаХатико, нет, так просто Вы не отделаетесь! Куча народа участвовала в этом процессе.

Вы уж утолите любопытство, расскажите в чем дело-то было.

Comment: ) ну вы меня запозорите просто...
я на запись файл открывала в режиме "w"

Comment: Вот и славно, плюсую.

Answer (score 2):

Хм, по ощущениям проблема в передаче файла неверного размера - это проблема сервера. Проверь там. Это математика, запиши в переменную сумму переданных байт и сравни с размером файла.

Какой размер buff1? Как создается переменная? Здесь может быть выход за предел выделенной памяти. Не понял шутку (n1-1), должно быть n1; Или нужно передать без восклицательного знака?

И да, один совет. Для программы есть файлы, ей плевать на расширения. Она либо работает, либо нет. Она не может падать от конкретных расширений. Тут другая причина, например длинна имени файла.

Comment: Я занялся, как и хотел, TFTP, но он оказался не таким простым, как показалось сначала. К тому же я пишу его с нуля. Он скорее долгий по времени, чем по сложности. Обещает быть шедевром. Может завтра допишу сервер.

Comment: @mikelsv Насчёт шедевра -- за язык Вас никто не тянул.

Comment: @mikelsv, для какой ОС пишите? UDP или свою версию для TCP? Второе может быть даже интересней.

Comment: @avp TFTP для TCP? Это как? Т.е. что-то похожее написать можно, но (1) это уже не TFTP (2) лишние детали останутся.

Comment: @alexlz, rfc1350 не навязывает UDP. Там просто пишут, что они реализовали TFTP на UDP и обсуждают организацию "виртуального соединения" при использовании UDP.

Более того, ну кому нужен yaTFTP (yet another)? А вот TCP это нечто новое, такая библиотека и утилиты (клиенты и сервер) могут выглядеть привлекательно, да и для реализации IMHO проще. 

Да, к rfc1350 надо подойти творчески, делать просто в том же духе.

Comment: Пишу для Windows. Поправить под линукс будет делом пяти минут. На UDP. Тут самое интересное в отсутствии потоков, они не нужны, и это очень упрощает программу. Блокировок тоже нет. Идеальная программа для обучения.

TFTP через TCP? Хмм, да может выйти неплохая вещь. Даже проще FTP, который создает соединение на каждый файл и на запрос списка файлов.

Если вас интересует тема простой передачи файлов, то вполне можно подыскать протоколы получше или написать свой. Где в одном соединении передается все, что попросишь.

Comment: @mikelsv, хорошая развлекуха. Планируете только утилиты или библиотеку (API) тоже?

Если библиотеку, то советую писать ее на чистом Си, чтобы расширить круг языков из которых ее можно использовать. Для С++ можно сделать поверх нее некую "обертку" для реализации исключений и т.п.

Надеюсь, через некоторое время сможем обсудить реализацию.